# Straight forward way to run ssh-agent and ssh-add on login via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, bashrc, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to have the following commands be auto-executed when I login to my server via ssh:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

My ssh key has a passphrase and I'm fine with entering it once per login.

I tried putting this in my .bashrc file, however I believe that ssh-agent starts a new bash session. When I try to login after having this in my .bashrc, it gets stuck, and I have to type 'exit' to then see the 'enter passphrace to unlock key' prompt

Any other suggestions?

Server is running Ubuntu LTS

Comment: Why key agent on the server?  It should be on your local **client** that you are connecting from.

Comment: @Zoredache I want to be able to do `git pull` and such on the remote server

Comment: Then run an SSH agent on your local machine, and forward the agent.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks, didn't know that was possible. However I'd still like to be able to do ssh-add / ssh-agent from within a bash script, even from my local machine. Its a pain to have to run those commands manually.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and works perfectly! It requires typing your ssh keys only once per reboot of your remote server: [Unix & Linux: How can I run ssh-add automatically, without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/114401)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can try adding this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This way the `ssh-agent` does not start a new shell, it just launches itself in the background and spits out the shell commands to set the appropriate environment variables.

As said in the comment, maybe you do **not** want to run the agent at all on the remote host, but rather on the box you are working from, and use

```
ssh -A remote-host
```

to forward the services of your local ssh agent to the remote-host.

For security reasons you should only use agent forwarding with hosts run by trustworthy people, but it is better than running a complete agent remotely any time.

Comment: When I replace `ssh-agent /bin/bash` with `ssh-agent -s`, and then I try to do `git pull`, I'm still asked for the passphrase of the private key to unlock it. That's not really what I want, I want to only have to enter the passphrase on doing ssh-add, and not have to repeat it each time I run any git commands. Any ideas?

Comment: and running the agent locally and using ssh -A is not an option for you? The problem is, that you can not 'restart' the ssh-agent on every connection. Every time you start it, it knows 'nothing' and when you ssh-add the key you will have to decrypt it ...

Comment: for your .ssh/config file:
Host remote-host
    ControlMaster auto 
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%l-%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 2h

Comment: Running ssh -A works fine. The problem is, I'd just like to have a bash script which runs `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` , rather than have to run those separately each time. I'm fine with running this script manually and then doing ssh -A. The problem is, running `ssh-agent` from a bash script doesn't work. And if I do `ssh-agent -S`, then doing `git pull` still asks for the pass phrase.

Comment: I think the problem is this: "it just launches itself in the background and spits out the shell commands to set the appropriate environment variables." I assume that after running `ssh-agent -S` I'd need to set those env. variables before `git pull` will work. Can that be done automatically from a bash script? That way I just have to run `ssh.sh` and enter my passphrase, and from there everything works on auto pilot.

Comment: if the ssh-agent is running and the environment variable are set, then the keys will be added to is automatically after first use ...I guess I am not quite sure what your use case is ... it would help if you edited your question with the commands you expect to be able to run. Also note that running a bash script and executing .bashrc are two different things. If you set a variable in a bash script it can never affect the calling process. Environment variable changes will not work backwards. You may want to setup an alias for such a purpose.

Comment: The environment variables are not set.. I'm wondering if there's a way to set them automatically when `ssh-agent -S` is run?

Comment: I'd like to ideally run one single command, either an alias or a bash script, which in turn starts ssh-agent and calls ssh-add . And then I enter my passphrase once and no longer have to enter it again.

Comment: could it be that you work on host a, login to host b, start the agent, run your git command, log out of b, and then login to b again ? in that case your agent connection will get lost every time ... unless you run your agent on host a and use ssh -A to log into b.

Comment: Connecting is not even an issue. This is limited to my own machine now. I'm just looking for a simple way to have ssh-agent and ssh-add be executed via a bash script or such on my own machine. Is that possible?

Comment: note that the environment variables only get inherited by the children of your process ... so in a desktop environment, ssh-agent normally gets launched in the startup phase and is the 'parent' of most of the processes and they thus inherit its environment variables ... your distribution should actually take care of this.

Comment: On my local machine, I open shell, run `ssh-agent -S`. It outputs the variables. And then I run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. It says key was added. Then in the same session I run `git pull` which works if I run `ssh-agent /bin/bash`, however it asks me for the pass phrase to unlock it. So `ssh-agent -S` is not working.

Comment: you have to run `\`ssh-agent -s\`` note the backticks!!

Comment: `bash: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-AmnQ6sdALZOT/agent.3986;: No such file or directory`

Comment: oops just realised in bash you need an extra eval in front of the ssh-agent call .. updated my answer above

Comment: I've made a bash script which contains the `eval ssh-agent -s` and `ssh-add` lines as you gave (with backticks). When I run this, I get the output: `Agent pid 3328 Enter passphrase for /home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa)`. However, after this if I try `git pull`, I'm still prompted to enter keyphrase to unlock the key, which sucks. If I run `ps -aux | grep ssh` I can see that the agent is running. If I subsitute `ssh-agent /bin/bash` for `eval ssh-agent -s`, then `git pull` works. But that can't be put in a bash script. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, because the bash script will run in a separate process, it can not influence the environment of the calling process ..

Comment: so there's no way to do what i want?

Comment: you could create an alias

Comment: Thanks. My saga has finally come to an end. in ~/.bashrc I have : alias gitssh='eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa' . And with that, its finally working the way I want it to. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to add this to your .bashrc. This has the same advantage as Erik's answer (ensuring a single instance) but doesn't require an additional package.

```
# SSH Agent should be running, once
runcount=$(ps -ef | grep "ssh-agent" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l)
if [ $runcount -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Starting SSH Agent
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
fi
```

This runs ssh-add if there is not at least 1 key loaded and sets a key timeout of 1 day:

```
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
if ! [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
     echo Adding keys...
     ssh-add -t 1d
fi
```

Comment: If ssh-agent is already running, but without any keys loaded, this doesn't call ssh-add. Better add another condition and check the output of `ssh-add -l` - if it is >0, run something like `ssh-add -t 4h`

Answer (score 9):

One alternative is to use Funtoo's [Keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain). Then you can stick this one-liner in your bash shell:

```
eval $(keychain --eval id_rsa)
```

That does the same thing (launches ssh agent, etc.), while also not running an ssh-agent process for each subshell.  Instead it looks for "already running" instances you own and attaches you to them.

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as @womblerone, but a little bit slimmer:

Run the ssh agent (if not already running):

```bash
# SSH Agent should be running, once
if ! ps -ef | grep "[s]sh-agent" &>/dev/null; then
    echo Starting SSH Agent
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
fi
```

Add the ssh-key if no keys are added yet

```bash
if ! ssh-add -l &>/dev/null; then
     echo Adding keys...
     ssh-add -t 1d
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind if you have ssh connection keep-alive you need to delete existing connection files before `-A` takes effect. Delete any ssh connection files in `/tmp/[host]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you used both `zsh` (Oh-my-zsh) and `bash` I have written this this little script that is compatible with it.

```bash
SHORT_HOST="${HOSTNAME/.*/}"
ssh_env_cache="$HOME/.ssh/environment-$SHORT_HOST"

# Oh-my-zsh compatible bash ssh-agent start script
function _start_agent() {
    if [[ -f "$ssh_env_cache" ]]; then
        . "$ssh_env_cache" > /dev/null
    fi

    if [[ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
      return 0
    fi

    echo "Starting ssh-agent ..."
    ssh-agent -s | sed '/^echo/d' > "$ssh_env_cache"
    chmod 600 "$ssh_env_cache"
    . "$ssh_env_cache" > /dev/null
}
_start_agent

unset ssh_env_cache
unset -f _start_agent

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

On the plus side this will prevent spawning another `ssh-agent` every time you start a `bash` session.